# Not able to see table created through spring boot java

Tags: java, database, spring-boot, h2

[image]I am trying to see my table created through java in H2 console, but i cannot see any table created in H2 console. I am using spring boot, and i am not using spring security, just i have created a simple dummy code to try H2 database for understanding. I have tried many solutions provided on questions asked on the same topic on stack-overflow but non of them works for me.

My Config property file is:

1. spring.h2.console.enabled=true
2. spring.datasource.platform=h2
3. spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:D:/temp/test

Entity class code are as follows:

```
@Entity
public class Alien {

    @Id
    private int aId;
    private String aName;

    public int getaId() {
        return aId;
    }

    public void setaId(int aId) {
        this.aId = aId;
    }

    public String getaName() {
        return aName;
    }

    public void setaName(String aName) {
        this.aName = aName;
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you log in to your H2 console in the browser you have to specify the JDBC URL to your database as you don't use the default in-memory one.

Your JDBC URL is `jdbc:h2:file:D:/temp/test`. Once you specify this URL in the H2 console *login screen*, put in the correct username and password, you should be able to see your file-based local database.

[image]

Comment: Hi i am using the same jdbc:h2:file:D:/temp/test as jdbc URL but still i can't see table, i have tried with default in-memory database and same issue occurring.

Answer (score 0):

Use @Table for creatting a table from entity class

```
@Entity
```

@Table(name="alien")
public class Alien {

```
@Id
private int aId;
private String aName;

public int getaId() {
    return aId;
}

public void setaId(int aId) {
    this.aId = aId;
}

public String getaName() {
    return aName;
}

public void setaName(String aName) {
    this.aName = aName;
}
```

}